# Automatic initializer Inheritance's condition is the Initializer's signature

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

The `Food` class is the superclass of `RecipeIngredient`.

`Food` class introduced one variable named `name` and one designated initializer `init(name: String)` and a convenience initializer `init()`;

`RecipeIngredient` class introduced a new variable named `quantity` and one designated initializer `init(name: String, quantity: Int)` and a convenience initializer `init(name: String)`

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "[Unnamed]")
    }
}

class RecipeIngredient: Food {
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, quantity: Int) {
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name: name)
    }
    override convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
    }
}

let oneMysteryItem = RecipeIngredient()
print("\(oneMysteryItem.name), \(oneMysteryItem.quantity)")//--> [Unnamed], 1
```

Quote from the [office document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

> Even though `RecipeIngredient` provides the `init(name: String)` initializer as a convenience initializer, `RecipeIngredient` has nonetheless provided an implementation of all of its superclass’s designated initializers. Therefore, `RecipeIngredient` automatically inherits all of its superclass’s convenience initializers too.

**Question1**: The convenience initializer of the subclass `RecipeIngredient` and the designated initializer of the superclass `Food` has the same signature, aka. `init(name: String)`. But they are totally different initializers! So, can I say, as long as there is an initializer in the subclass has the same signature with the superclass, it can be considered the subclass is provided the implication of the superclass's designated initializer

**Question2**: Since the `RecipeIngredient` class inherient the convinece initializer of the `Food` class. `let oneMysteryItem = RecipeIngredient()` is valid. but `print("\(oneMysteryItem.name), \(oneMysteryItem.quantity)")`  prints **[Unnamed], 1**, I really don't understand how this 1 comes from! What happed? The inherent convenience initializer only defined how to initialize the inherent value `name`, how this `quantity == 1` had been defined?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

The rule is that, if a subclass has ANY designated initializers and also overrides ALL of its superclass's DESIGNATED initializers  (marking them either as designated or as convenience in the subclass), the CONVENIENCE initializers of the superclass are inherited.

Question 2:

The `RecipeIngredient` has provided an overridden initializer of its superclass's only designated initializer (i.e., `init(name: String)`), therefore all the convenience initializers are inherited (i.e., in this case just `init()`). Calling `RecipeIngredient()` calls the `init()` convenience initializer which in turn calls `init(name: "[Unnamed]")` on the subclass, which in turn calls `init(name: "[Unnamed]", quantity: 1)`, the designated initializer of the subclass

Answer (score 1):

“The inherited version of init() functions in exactly the same way as the Food version, except that it delegates to the RecipeIngredient version of init(name: String) rather than the Food version.”

Source: [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) in “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1)”.